# Alter MediaWiki's user table

Tags: mediawiki

How can I change the default MySQL table "user" , that's used to store all members?

Answer (score 0):

is it more of a database question? in mysql you could issue command, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD COLUMN user_birthday DATE;
```

check the actual name of user table. MW uses table prefix option which may not be empty.

The actual statement will depend on what column you want to add of course.

However, **for the better portability** of your wiki (e.g. easier upgrade) you might want to create a new table instead for the user profile that would have user_id as `FOREIGN_KEY`

Also there is a field **user_options** which stores name=value pairs of extra data. - you can make use of that if you don't care about searching your DB against the new "field".

Answer (score 0):

**Do not**.

If you need to alter the `user` table (and related) server-side, use the appropriate [maintenance script](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:Maintenance_scripts): [createAndPromote.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:CreateAndPromote.php) is among the most used, there are others for specific functions.

You didn't specify your use case, but chances are that you're going to break MediaWiki in unexpected ways if you try to manually alter the table.

Answer (score -1):

[Here is some information about the "user" table.](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_table)